# How can i get current username in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle

i have some code

```
create or replace function policy_test (p_schema varchar2, p_object varchar2)
return varchar2 is
    v VARCHAR2(30);
begin
    v := USER;
    return 'name = ' ||  v;
end;

Begin
DBMS_RLS.add_policy (
   object_schema => 'system',
   object_name  => 'WORKMAN',
   policy_name  => 'WORKMAN_policy_test2',
   function_schema => 'system',
   policy_function  => 'policy_test',
   statement_types => 'select',
   update_check => true
);
End;
```

and i'd like to ruturn 'name=system' or 'name=Jack' from function policy_test, but i get some error :

[28113] ORA-28113 policy predicate has error

How can i get current user name in policy_test and return sting like 'name=Jack' ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740973/ora-28113-policy-predicate-has-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Predicate Error with Oracle VPD/RLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957425/predicate-error-with-oracle-vpd-rls)

Comment: it looks like the truth,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your particular VPD policy will append the return value to an implicit WHERE clause. The problem lies in your desired behavior. You stated, "and i'd like to return 'name=system' or 'name=Jack' from function policy_test"

If you were to write out an SQL statement like this: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name=system` or `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name=Jack`, what would happen? The query will fail every time. When doing string comparison in a WHERE clause, you must enclose the string literal with single tick marks. Change it to `WHERE name = 'Jack'` and you have valid SQL.

Back to your function. Your function is returning a string, `name=Jack` and so `WHERE name=Jack` is what Oracle is generating. You haven't quoted the string literal so the SQL fails. The nature of VPD hides the exception raised (very frustrating) but Oracle does log it in the trace file.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i need to transform variable v from context like this  v := USER; to string type and then concatenation it : return 'name = ' ||  v;

Comment: Use concatenate to add the apostrophes. There are three methods for doing this. The one I use is the double single quote. You can also use the `q` method or `chr(39)`. `return 'name = ''' || v || '''';`